# Desestructuración en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, restful

Estoy trabajando en una RESTFULL API con node y postgresql, tengo unos problemas cuando recibo  la solicitud e intento desestructurar los parámetros en el cuerpo de la petición.

Tengo un archivo llamado main.js que contiene el siguiente código.

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
server = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
server.use(morgan('dev'));
server.use(require('./rutas/router'));
server.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
server.use(express.json());

const mensaje = `Servidor escuchando peticiones en el puerto ${port}`;
console.log(mensaje);
```

y tengo un archivo llamado router.js que maneja las rutas del servidor, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();
const {Pool} = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
    host: 'myhost',
    user: 'myusr',
    password: 'mypasswd',
    database: 'mydb',
    port: '5432',
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    max: 20
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('<h1>Página principal</h1>');
});

router.get('/productos', async(req, res) => {
    await pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error conectando el cliente.', err.stack);
            return res.status(400).send('Ocurrio un error en la conexión con la base de datos.');
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM producto', (err, result) => {
            release();
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error al ejecutar la consulta a la base de datos', err.stack);
                return res.status(400).send('Ocurrio un error al ejecutar la consulta con la base de datos');
            }
            console.log(result.rows);
            pool.end();
            return res.status(200).json(result.rows);
        });
    });
});

router.post('/productos', async(req, res) => {
    const {nombre, descripcion, precio} = req.body;
    await pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error conectando el cliente.', err.stack);
            return res.status(400).send('Ocurrio un error en la conexión con la base de datos');
        }
        client.query('INSERT INTO producto (nombre, descripcion, precio) VALUES($1, $2, $3)', [nombre, descripcion, precio], (err, result) => {
            release();
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error al ejecutar la consulta a la base de datos.', err.stack);
                return res.status(400).send('Ocurrio un error al ejecutar la consulta con la base de datos');
            }
            console.log(result.rows);
            pool.end();
            return status(200).json({respuesta: true, producto: {nombre: nombre, descripcion: descripcion, precio: precio}});
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Mi problema está en la petición POST a la ruta /productos para almacenar la información de un producto, no puedo aplicar des estructuración en el req.body porque me toma la petición como undefined. En el main.js yo he utilizado las opciones para trabajar con urlconded y json para poder leer los datos del cuerpo de la petición pero aún así me arroja un error. He intentado de todo y no he podido dar con el problema, no quiero comenzar desde cero, aunque es un proyecto simple, porque quiero descubrir el problema y no rendirme.

Tengo entendido que existe la libreria body-parser, pero me dijeron que express trae esas funcionalidades, espero no estar equivocado, anteriormente he realizado una APIRESTFULL con los mismos métodos y me ha funcionado, pero está vez no puedo recibir el cuerpo de la solicitud.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, soy nuevo trabajando con JavaScript.

Comment: Que es lo que se envía en el post?

Comment: Se envía el nombre, descripción y precio del producto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probaste hacerle un print al req para ver si esta llegando el payload?
Lo otro, coloca estas 2 líneas

```
server.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
server.use(express.json());
```

antes del `server.use(require('./rutas/router'))`

Comment: Claramente estaba declarando estas líneas debajo de las rutas y las rutas no estaban haciendo el parseo de las solicitudes. Se me olvida el flujo de ejecución de JavaScript.